# API Google MAPS localização a partir do endereço

Tags: javascript, html5, apache-cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Tenho um endereço salvo no banco de dados, dividido corretamente e preciso a partir deste endereço gerar a latitude e a longitude e alem disto plotar no mapa um marcado na área cadastrada.

```
SGL_ENDER_ESTAD: "MG"
TXT_ENDER_BAIRR: "MEU BAIRRO"
TXT_ENDER_CEPXX: "MEU CEP"
TXT_ENDER_CIDAD: "MINHA CIDADE"
TXT_ENDER_COMPL: null
TXT_ENDER_LOGRA: "MINHA RUA"
TXT_ENDER_NUMER: "MEU NUMERO"
```

Não tenho nada feito ainda sobre o assunto, pois não conheço muito da API, gostaria que alguém me ajuda-se a dar inicio a produção, ou me passa-se um site ou vídeo que seria como tutorial para o meu problema.

> Um detalhe, preciso tudo sendo feito com JQuery ou JavaScript, outro detalhe é que meu projeto é mobile, e utilizo o HTML5 + Cordova.

Tem como ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize a API `GeoCode`.

Exemplo:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20Rio%20Branco,%20Rio%20de%20Janeiro&sensor=false

Retornará as coordenadas da Avenida Rio Branco no Rio de Janeiro:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         [...],
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -22.8960696,
                  "lng" : -43.1737186
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -22.9147546,
                  "lng" : -43.1812468
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -22.9055697,
               "lng" : -43.1774453
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -22.8960696,
                  "lng" : -43.1737186
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -22.9147546,
                  "lng" : -43.1812468
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJvxA4RV5_mQARIFeLysc-ZjY",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Esta API entende linguagem natural; você pode concatenar seus campos do banco de dados e utilizá-los no parâmetro `address`.

UIma vez de posse das coordenadas, você pode utilizar a API Simple Markers para exibir o mapa com a coordenada:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Este é um exemplo usando um dos pares de coordenadas recebido acima:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.8960696, -43.1737186);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
        draggable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(a) {
        console.log(a);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = a.latLng.lat().toFixed(4) + ', ' + a.latLng.lng().toFixed(4);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    });
};
```

```css
#map {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Irei estudar, porem como pegarei a lat e a lon correta do endereço ? Pois em seu exemplo apareceu varias. e como plotaria no mapa ? Teria como fazer um exemplo ne algum site  ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues utilize a chave `GEOMETRIC_CENTER`. Essa indica, literamente, o meio da estrutura selecionada.

Comment: como irei passar as informações em json para o geocoder ?  Me auxilie nisto ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues O GeoCoder recebe texto (via `QueryString`) e retorna um JSON. Eu atualizei a resposta com um exemplo de visualização do mapa.

Comment: Aonde no seu codigo que você passa o endereço ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues no primeiro link presente na minha resposta.

Comment: Porque esta parte esta ok. Porem como irei pegar a lat e a long do endereço que tenho do banco de dados ?

Comment: Tipo não sei como irei fazer para enviar o endereço para link.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues Esta é uma outra pergunta, que foge um pouco do escopo desta. Sinta-se à vontade para criar uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Amigo tire a ultima duvida, conseguir fazer a requisição e está me retornando o json certinho, porem nao estou conseguindo acessar a lat e a long do GEOMETRIC_CENTER. estou fazendo seguinte. `lat = dados.geometry.location.lat` e não esta dando como faço isto ?]

Comment: @RenanRodrigues tente `dados.results.geometry.location.lat`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29941/discussion-between-onosendai-and-renan-rodrigues).

Comment: Depois de muito tempo procurando, esta resposta me ajudou!

Comment: @LeonardoMax Fico feliz em ler isso. Bom proveito!

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado pela sua excelente resposta, já me deu uma boa noção sobre como poderei implementar uma funcionalidade que surgiu do nada aqui kkk Deus abençoe!

Answer (score 1):

Tem como sim, recomendo a leitura da documentação da API e visualização dos exemplos.
Eu não sabia nada da API também, mas usando os exemplos consegui implementar algo parecido bem rápido.

Se liga nesses exemplos:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ acredito que vá encontrar tudo que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Segue exemplo desenvolvido com angular.

Link projeto: https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/tree/master/google-maps-custom/src/main/webapp

App:

```
var app = angular.module("GoogleMapsCustom", ["uiGmapgoogle-maps"]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("GoogleMapsCustomController", function($scope) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: -23.586172, longitude: -46.657085 }, zoom: 10};
    $scope.map.randomMarkers = [];
    var adressOfCustomer = [
                             ["BAZAR BARAO LTDA ME", "AV.JOAO XXIII,84-V.FORMOSA, SP"],                                          
                             ["MAGAZINE BELEZA CENTER LTDA", "AV DOS IGARAPES, 1571, SP"],                                                
                             ["ESTACIONAMENTO CARREIRA LTDA ME", "AV.SAPOPEMBA,3016 SAPOPEMBA, SP"],                                          
                             ["LUIS GONZAGA GARDINALI ME", "R.FREI CANECA,22 - CENTRO, SP"],                                             
                             ["A R NETTO", "R.ANTONIO GONCALVES TEIXEIRA, 53, SP"],                                     
                             ["O DONEGA MOJI MIRIM ", "R.BUTANTA, 17-PINHEIROS, SP"],                                               
                             ["MAGAZINE MISS ELEGAN LTDA", "R GOVERNADOR PEDRO DE TOLEDO 1021, SP"],                                   
                             ["O.Y.OKI & CIA.LTDA ", "R.JOSE BONIFACIO,60, SP"]
                         ];

    $scope.setMarkers = function(numberOfMarkers) {
        setLatitudeAndLongitudeByAdress(adressOfCustomer, $scope.map);
    };

    $scope.onMarkerClicked = function(marker){
        marker.showWindow = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    };
});

app.controller("InfoController", function($scope) {
    $scope.templateValue = 'hello from the template itself';
    $scope.clickedButtonInWindow = function() {
        var msg = 'clicked a window in the template!';
        $log.info(msg);
        alert(msg);
    }
});

function setLatitudeAndLongitudeByAdress(adressOfCustomer, map){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    angular.forEach(adressOfCustomer, function(value, key) {
        var adress = value[1];
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adress + ', Brasil', 'region': 'BR' }, function (results, status) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var customer = value[0];
            var itemMap = {
                latitude : latitude,
                longitude : longitude,
                title : customer,
                id : key,
                adress : adress,
                date : "10/11/2015"
            };
            map.randomMarkers.push(itemMap);
        });
    });
}

function init(){

    var adressOfCustomer = [
        ["BAZAR BARAO LTDA ME", "AV.JOAO XXIII,84-V.FORMOSA, SP"],                                          
        ["MAGAZINE BELEZA CENTER LTDA", "AV DOS IGARAPES, 1571, SP"],                                                
        ["ESTACIONAMENTO CARREIRA LTDA ME", "AV.SAPOPEMBA,3016 SAPOPEMBA, SP"],                                          
        ["LUIS GONZAGA GARDINALI ME", "R.FREI CANECA,22 - CENTRO, SP"],                                             
        ["A R NETTO", "R.ANTONIO GONCALVES TEIXEIRA, 53, SP"],                                     
        ["O DONEGA MOJI MIRIM ", "R.BUTANTA, 17-PINHEIROS, SP"],                                               
        ["MAGAZINE MISS ELEGAN LTDA", "R GOVERNADOR PEDRO DE TOLEDO 1021, SP"],                                   
        ["O.Y.OKI & CIA.LTDA ", "R.JOSE BONIFACIO,60, SP"]
    ];

    var locationOfCustomer = getLatitudeAndLongitudeByAdress(adressOfCustomer);
    initializeMaps(locationOfCustomer);
}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Google Maps API v3: Busca de endereço e Autocomplete - Demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">

       </head>
    <body ng-app="GoogleMapsCustom">

        <h1>Google Maps Multiple Marker Demo 123</h1>


        <div ng-controller="GoogleMapsCustomController" ng-init="setMarkers();">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"> <ui-gmap-markers models="map.randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" click="onMarkerClicked" doCluster="map.doClusterRandomMarkers"
                clusterOptions="map.clusterOptions" modelsbyref="true"> 
                <ui-gmap-windows show="'showWindow'" closeClick="'closeClick'" ng-cloak>
                    <div>
                        <p ng-non-bindable>{{title}} - endereço: {{adress}} visita: {{date}}<button type='button'>Incluir na Agenda</button></p>
                    </div>
                    </ui-gmap-windows> 
                </ui-gmap-markers> 
            </ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aqueles que chegarem nesta solução, o link está desatualizado. O atual:
https://github.com/emirdeliz/angular-google-maps