# Adicionar mapa com serviço de busca usando angularjs e google maps

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

Possuo mapa e desejo que neste possa ser localizado e marcado um determinado ponto mediante ao endereço passado pelo usuário.
Exemplo: 
O usuário digita : rua são joão,403, São Paulo, Sp.
O mapa deve retornar o ponto no mapa referente ao endereço informado.
html

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDij4Z3AFhetKwsKd9dP6gd0jPceh4Y70I"></script>
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" events="map_events">
    <ui-gmap-marker idkey="123" coords="unit.coordinates" options="{ draggable: true }" events="marker_events"></ui-gmap-marker>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

js

```html
app.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    key: 'AIzaSyDij4Z3AFhetKwsKd9dP6gd0jPceh4Y70I',
    v: '3.20',
    libraries: 'places,weather,geometry,visualization'
  });
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Eu quero habilitar a busca aí e não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a API GeoCode.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=rua são joão,403, São Paulo, Sp
```

Retorna um objeto que contém, inclusive, a propriedade `geometry.location` : `{ "lat" : -23.4346994, "lng" : -46.7748177}`.

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90949/1897).